# Sorting posts by most liked over the past 24 hours on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, psql

Currently my app is using the [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) gem and the default_scope is set to order posts by most up votes. All votes are cached, as seen in the acts_as_votable documentation. However after time my content will get stale, so I would like to have user posts sorted by most votes over the past 24 hours, similar to reddit.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_votable
    default_scope { order(:cached_votes_up => :desc) } 
end
```

Additionally here is the schema.rb for the votes table, which has a created at field.

```
create_table "votes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "votable_id"
    t.string   "votable_type"
    t.integer  "voter_id"
    t.string   "voter_type"
    t.boolean  "vote_flag"
    t.string   "vote_scope"
    t.integer  "vote_weight"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Thanks in advance. Feel free to ask any questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_votable
    default_scope { where(:created_at => ((Time.current - 24.hours)..Time.current)) }
    default_scope { order(:cached_votes_up => :desc) }
end
```

Something like that. You can have more than one default_scope and they are merged.